# How do these values take precedence in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS and am confused by **relative layout**. What happens if you give conflicting property values for positioning? For example `left: 50px;` and `right 50px;`

I've tried myself and from what I can tell, `right` always gets dropped if there is both `left` and `right`. Also what about `top` vs `bottom`?

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>position: relative;</h2>

<p>Lorem Ipsum insert text here....</p>

<div class="relative">
This div element has position: relative;
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/right):

> When both the right CSS property and the left CSS property are defined, the position of the element is overspecified. In that case, the left value has precedence when the container is left-to-right (that is that the right computed value is set to -left), and the right value has precedence when the container is right-to-left (that is that the left computed value is set to -right).

So, when `direction: ltr`, `left` has precedence. When `direction: rtl`, `right` has precedence.

For `top` and `bottom` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top)):

> When both top and bottom are specified, as long as height is
>   unspecified, auto or 100%, both top and bottom distances will be
>   respected. Otherwise, if height is constrained in any way, the top
>   property takes precedence and the bottom property is ignored.

Comment: It also seems `top` overrides `bottom` but I can't find that in the documentation.